# How to start a background service daily only when I turn on internet connection?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, background-service

I want when I turn internet connection on at any hour of the day, a background service start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple bash to ping google once, if you got ping, then your internet is ONLINE. Start you program. If there is no internet stop the program.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com >/dev/null; 
then
sudo systemctl start YourProgram                   
else
sudo systemctl stop YourProgram
fi
```

Now just alter the code after your needs. You can even place it in a loop.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I want a background service start when I turn on internet connection at any hour of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Use **WorkManager** with **PeriodicWorkRequest** with **Constraints** like below:

```
    Constraints myConstraints = 
        new Constraints.Builder().
        setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).
        build(); 

    PeriodicWorkRequest mywork = 
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS).
        setConstraints(myConstraints).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().
        enqueue(mywork);
```